# itemCount lenght leaving space

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a program like this, it doesn't give any errors, but item.lengt takes the whole lesson class, the program leaves spaces instead of eliminated ones(showed in code).

I can't eliminate the list above because I have completed the index there and I can't get it up.

```
    return BlocBuilder(
    bloc: _lessonsBloc,
    builder: (BuildContext context, LessonsState state) {

    if (state is LessonsLoading) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (state is LessonsLoaded) {
      return ListView.builder(


     //here need to change
        itemCount: state.lessons.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       //Here I eliminate items from my list its because my index here :/
          final displayedLessons = state.lessons[index];
            if(tab.text == displayedLessons.day){ 
              return ListTile(
            title: Text(displayedLessons.name),
            subtitle:
                Text(displayedLessons.subname),
            trailing: _buildUpdateDeleteButtons(displayedLessons), 
          );
            } else{print('nope');}
              return ListTile();           
        },
      );
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },

);
}
```

I'd be happy if I could figure this out, but I think I should use another widget.i just need an idea.

```
https://pasteboard.co/Ivr3FjK.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/Ivr4gRU.jpg
https://pasteboard.co/Ivr4piY.jpg
```

Comment: Just return `Container()` wherever you want to eliminate/not display the item for some reason.

Comment: Oh it really worked thank you and i want to ask 
Is there a better way to do this? this looks a little bad code to me, if u give an aswer not comment i can accept thank you again

Comment: I think this is the best way of achieving what your trying to do, as far as I know,

Comment: I have added the solution in the form of an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general-case solution:

Whenever you want to skip a Widget from a builder function for a given condition (e.g. `ListView.builder`), just conditionally return an empty `Container()` with no dimensions whenever that given condition does not satisfy.

Example Code (for ListView.builder):

```
ListView.builder
  (
    itemCount: 10,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
       i=i+1;
       if(i%2==0) return Text(i.toString());
       else return Container();
    }
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
return BlocBuilder(
    bloc: _lessonsBloc,
    builder: (BuildContext context, LessonsState state) {

    if (state is LessonsLoading) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    } else if (state is LessonsLoaded) {
      //changes
      if(state.lessons.length==0)
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      else
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: state.lessons.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       //Here I eliminate items from my list its because my index here :/
          final displayedLessons = state.lessons[index];
            if(tab.text == displayedLessons.day){ 
              return ListTile(
            title: Text(displayedLessons.name),
            subtitle:
                Text(displayedLessons.subname),
            trailing: _buildUpdateDeleteButtons(displayedLessons), 
          );
            } else{print('nope');}
              return ListTile();           
        },
      );
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator();

  },

);
```

I havent't tried it. Though it seems working. Let me know if something Went wrong.

Comment: warned to forget return i added not problem but not worked same :/ i editted for screen shots

Comment: Mohit shetty's comment worked nevertheless thank you